# Alternative to grep

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I'm looking for some pattern in 1.txt out of 2.txt, using "`grep`". Then do some manipulation.
However, seems "`grep`" is too slow for large text.

```
for (( i=1; i<=236410; i++ ))
do 
    head -$i 1.txt|tail -1|grep -f - 2.txt|awk '{mul+=$4*$7} END {print $1,$2,$3,mul}'
done > file1
```

I'm just wondering any alternative? Seems `awk/sed` can do this, but just don't know how to pipe the variable `head -$i 1.txt|tail -1` into awk or sed

thx

Comment: Your `head` / `tail` combo is what's slow.

Comment: Yes, why are you going one line at a time instead of the whole thing?

Comment: how can I go by the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your pattern file has 236,410 lines, and assuming `grep` can handle that amount of input, and assuming the output file's order is not significant, why not just do

```
grep -f 1.txt 2.txt | awk ... >file1
```

If memory is an issue, and your input is static strings, try with `fgrep` instead; it can handle a larger amount of patterns.  If the order of the output is in fact significant, something like this should be a lot faster;

```
while read line; do
  grep "$line" 2.txt | awk ...
done <1.txt >file1
```

Depending on the input, you may want to muck with `IFS` and/or add some option to `read` to handle whitespace, backslashes etc.

If you only want the 236,410 first lines of input, you can change this to

```
head -n 236410 1.txt |
while read line ...
```

If none of the above suit you, here's another idea.  Since you are using `awk` for the actual processing anyway, you might be able to refactor all of the processing into an `awk` script, or create a `sed` script on the fly and pass the output of that to `awk`.  This is a bit involved, and again depends on what your patterns look like, but something like this should give you an idea:

```
sed 's%.*%/&/p%' 1.txt | less
```

What you are looking at is a `sed` script which prints if there's a match on each of the patterns in `1.txt`.  (It will break if any pattern contains a forward slash.  In the trivial case, use a different delimiter, or escape all slashes in the patterns.)  Now you can save that to a file, or (if your `sed` can handle a script on standard input) pass it to a second instance of `sed`:

```
sed 's%.*%/&/p%' 1.txt | sed -f - -n 2.txt | less
```

And that is what you would pass to `awk`:

```
sed 's%.*%/&/p%' 1.txt | sed -f - -n 2.txt | awk ... >file1
```